# Doctrine subquery andwhere

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm building up a large filter of if and where conditions using Doctrine.

The rough idea looks something like this:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select(...)->from(...)->joins(...)

if ($params['param1']) {
  $qb->where(...)
}

if ($params['param2']) {
  $qb->andWhere(...)
}

if ($params['param3']) {
  $qb->andWhere(...)
}
```

The issue I've hit is that I need to use an "andWhere" with an "orWhere" but I only want the "orWhere" to compare against this single "andWhere" and not the entire query that I've built up.

So it'll look something like this:

```
if ($params['param4']) {
  $qb->andWhere(...)
    ->orWhere(...)
}
```

If I do things like this then once I use the orWhere it'll ignore everything for param1, param2, param3 when all I want is for it to compare itself against param4s where condition.

I figured I needed to use a subquery but I'm really lost as to how to do that in Doctrine. Could someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: I recommend you to use `andWhere` instead of `where` at ther first call. It changes nothing for doctrine and avoid you to have your conditions reset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such cases, you can rely on the `Expr` class which contains the methods you need to build those more complex queries. Everything you need to know is explained in the Doctrine documentation in [the Query Builder section](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class).

The current documentation actually gives an example which almost fits with the use case you mentioned. You could write something like this for example:

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
   $qb->expr()->eq('u.id', '?1'),
   $qb->expr()->like('u.nickname', '?2')
));
```

The main advantage of relying on the `Expr` class is that you can pretty much write any kind of combination with it and it will produce the right DQL for it. It can get pretty verbose however.

That being said, you can also directly write your OR condition in the `andWhere`:

```
$qb->andWhere('u.id = ?1 OR u.nickname = ?2');
```